# Flutter: Handling Existing Subscriptions for Same Apple ID in In-App Purchases

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I am creating an app where i almost done the app development and just the in-app subscription left.
I have done some work on it too but not able to handle some scenarios which is listed below:

1-If the apple id from which the user logged-in in his/her iPhone didn't have already subscription the flow work just fine the the purchase happen and the upgrade api hit as well.

Now come with the scenario like if i already bought a subscription on my one account then i logged out and create a new account and go to buy subscription for my second account with same apple id here what happens listed below:

1- The ios popup shows that you already own this item and when i click on OK button the upgrade api still hit without making purchase.

I want to handle this senario and show to user that this apple id already have subscription and maybe other senario which till i haven't face need to be configure

The deadline is so close and i am dealing with IAP for first time
Any body to save will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = _iap.purchaseStream;

    _subscription =
        purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      for (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
        _iap.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (Object error) {});

    AddProvider addProvider = Provider.of<AddProvider>(context, listen: false);
    addProvider.initializeStatisticsPageInterstitialAd();
    handlePurchase();
    super.initState();
  }

  late StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;
  final List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = [];

// Inside your _listenToPurchaseUpdated method:
  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await _iap.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(
            context, 'Please wait while fetching details..');
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, 'Error');
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, 'Subscription is cancelled');
          _purchases.removeWhere(
              (element) => element.productID == purchaseDetails.productID);
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
            await hitUpgradeApi(
                pri, pdi, pdi == "monthly_subscription" ? "monthly" : "yearly");
            upgradeToPro(purchaseDetails);
          } else {
            if (context.mounted) {
              CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context,
                  'This apple id have already active subcription,change the id or logged in with relative subscribed account');
            }
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      st = purchaseDetails.status.toString();
      pdi = purchaseDetails.productID.toString();
      pri = purchaseDetails.purchaseID.toString();
      td = purchaseDetails.transactionDate.toString();
      if (st.isNotEmpty && pdi.isNotEmpty && pri.isNotEmpty && td.isNotEmpty) {
        return Future<bool>.value(true);
      }
    }
    CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, "Transaction failed");
    return Future<bool>.value(false);
  }

  Future<void> hitUpgradeApi(
      String purchaseTocken, String purchaseId, String plan) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        "purchase_token": purchaseTocken,
        "purchase_id": purchaseId,
        "plan": plan
      };
      Dio dio = await CommonData.createDioWithAuthHeader();
      Response response = await dio.post(CommonData.subcriptionApi, data: data);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (mounted) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, "Upgraded to pro");
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.type == DioExceptionType.unknown ||
          e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionError ||
          e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout) {
        if (mounted) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, "No internet connection");
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted) {
          CommonData.sshowDialog('Error', e.response!.data['message'], context);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool _isPurchased(String productId) {
    return _purchases.any((purchase) => purchase.productID == productId);
  }

  Future<void> handlePurchase() async {
    monthlyProductDetailsResponse = await _iap.queryProductDetails({
      'monthly_subscription',
    });
    yearlyProductDetailsResponse =
        await _iap.queryProductDetails({'yearly_subscription'});
  }

  Future<void> purchaseProduct(ProductDetails productDetails) async {
    try {
      final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
          PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
      final purchaseDetailss = await _iap.buyNonConsumable(
        purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
      );
      //  _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
      if (!purchaseDetailss) {
        if (context.mounted) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, "Some error occurred..");
        }
      } else {
        if (context.mounted) {
          CommonData.showCustomSnackbar(context, "Transaction failed");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      // completePurchase(productDetails.id);
    }
  }

  Future<void> upgradeToPro(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    _purchases.add(purchaseDetails);
  }
```